# Need for SSL in Tor?

Tags: ssl, tor

Some time ago, I read about [Facebook being accessible over Tor](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/can-officially-browse-facebook-tor/) and I couldn't ignore that their official URL https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/ not only shows HTTPS but a valid certificate issued for a .onion domain (actually the first in history).

Then the question came: given the nature of the Tor protocol, encrypting peer-to-peer communication, **why** using HTTPS? What advantages does it add to plain HTTP?

I'll share my conclusions in the answer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about network security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook give reasons for this in their [blog](https://www.facebook.com/notes/protect-the-graph/making-connections-to-facebook-more-secure/1526085754298237) when annoucing the TOR address

> We decided to use SSL atop this service due in part to architectural considerations - for example, we use the Tor daemon as a reverse proxy into a load balancer and Facebook traffic requires the protection of SSL over that link. As a result, we have provided an SSL certificate which cites our onion address; this mechanism removes the Tor Browser's “SSL Certificate Warning” for that onion address and increases confidence that this service really is run by Facebook. Issuing an SSL certificate for a Tor implementation is - in the Tor world - a novel solution to attribute ownership of an onion address; other solutions for attribution are ripe for consideration, but we believe that this one provides an appropriate starting point for such discussion.

Answer (score 2):

**SSL** (today TLS) is designed to **protect** data sent via wire and **authenticate** the server to which you are sending data (it can authenticate the client too, but it's out of the scope today). So if plain HTTP can be **eavesdropped** and **modified** by an attacker, HTTPS traffic can be happily sent over the channel with the assurance that *only* the *legitimate* recipient ("only" and "legitimate" emphasized separately).

Tor adds **anonymisation**. Plus to the above requirements, basically Tor prevents the client to be located. You know Facebook but Facebook won't know you. The Tor network, with its special sockets to `.onion` addresses, enforces encryption and authentication because only a host with a valid private key can register itself to a specific .onion domain.

So if you know `facebookcorewwwi` surely belongs to Facebook Inc., you don't need additional cryptography. Or do you?

Using a certificate still helps preventing phishing via domain scam. Onion domains are not regulated by ICANN so anyone can generate their own domain. [This article](https://timtaubert.de/blog/2014/11/using-the-webcrypto-api-to-generate-onion-names-for-tor-hidden-services/) explains that:

- Everybody can easily generate a `.onion` address that starts with a given prefix (e.g. `exampl`), but it gets incredibly slow to match longer prefixes
- If somebody was capable of generating `facebookcorewwwi`, he would be also able to break e-commerce level cryptography

So while nobody can steal Facebook's exclusive `facebookcorewwwi.onion` and nobody can eavesdrop traffic to `facebookcorewwwi.onion` maybe somebody lucky can still turn a victim into a site resembling Facebook's home page or worse named `facebookkernelwi.onion` etc.

Basically the answer is:

- An SSL certificate adds no additional security in Tor Onion domains when dealing with encryption
- An SSL certificate adds no additional authentication to the hostname in the `.onion` space, as anybody in the future might be able to obtain any `.onion` certificate
- **An SSL certificate with EV extension can prove the real identity of the owner of the authenticated `.onion` host**.

Facebook doesn't yet use EV for their Tor website as displayed below, but we know their Tor endpoint is currently experimental.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has used this to show its users that this crypto .onion address genuinely links to their own network and also to prove that its no phishing website but an ssl-encrypted one to prove its genuine identity.

Adding a SSL certificate to a .onion website using Lets Encrypt is the easiest to do preserving ur real identity as I have done it !